# Local JSON file in Custom WordPress Plugin is not loading my field groups?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I am having issues loading my custom fields from my local .json file within my plugin, Saving the fields work fine but the loading does work for my other field groups, am I missing something?

```
// ********** JSON File Path Save ACF Fields (this works fine!) **********

add_filter('acf/settings/save_json', 'my_acf_json_save_point');
 
function my_acf_json_save_point( $path ) {
    
    // update path HAVING ISSUES!!!
    $path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/acf/acf-json';
    
    // return
    return $path;
}

// ********** JSON File Path Load ACF Fields (this does not work??? ) **********

add_filter('acf/settings/load_json', 'my_acf_json_load_point');

function my_acf_json_load_point( $paths ) {
   // Remove original path
   unset( $paths[0] );// Append our new path
   $paths[] = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/acf/acf-json';
   
   return $paths;
}
```

Comment: Either `add_filter('acf/settings/load_json'...` is never runs or it runs after the hook has already fired. 

BTW. are u calling `get_field()` somewhere before your code?

Comment: No I am not calling `get_field()` I am not sure how I would do that, would you mind showing me the correct syntax?

Comment: It's worth to try removing default filters and then adding your own, also I would rather use `array_push()` - code here: https://www.codepile.net/pile/GnN5plZw

Comment: Thanks I am trying that, do you have any thoughts on why `add_filter('acf/settings/url', 'my_acf_settings_url');
function my_acf_settings_url(  $url ) {
    return MY_ACF_URL;
}` is not working for me to pull in tyhe assets?